# Code Review Secret Santa 2015: Show off your gifts

Tags: discussion, fun

Now that some of the gifts have been sent and begin to arrive, you can show off your awesome christmas swag in here and write a "*Thank You*" message to your giftee!

Don't worry if your gift hasn't arrived yet, good things take time. If you haven't received your gift by the 10th of January, let @TopinFrassi or @DanPantry know in the [CR Secret Santa chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32409/cr-secret-santa-2015).

You don't have to be in your photo, but please post a picture of your gift and anything you want to say to your giftee!

On behalf of all the participants of this year's Secret Santa, I want to say a big thanks to @TopinFrassi and @DanPantry for organising everything, the moderators  for letting us go through with this and everyone who participated for being kind santas:

[Topin Frassi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40395/topinfrassi), [Dan Pantry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42325/dan-pantry), [janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos), [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug), [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl), [Joe Wallis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/joe-wallis), [Phrancis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42632/phrancis), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Ethan Bierlein](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53251/ethan-bierlein) and [Zak](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/81541/zak).

Thanks everyone and have a Merry Christmas!

<sub>Format borrowed from [A&M's Secret Santa show-off](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/am-gift-exchange-show-off-your-gifts).</sub>

Comment: It's been a breeze to organize, you guys were cool on participation! :) Can't wait to see everyone's gifts!

Answer (score 21):

Time to break the book trend...
I'm one of those people that can't think of anything for gifts,
sorry Santa.
But I really like the present, I didn't have my own mug, so thank you!

---

[image: Mug when empty/cold]
[image: Mug when hot]

Comment: Wait a sec.. the score changes when you pour coffee into it?? Or, it's *playable*?? How did the game advance 10 levels between the top and bottom pictures??

Comment: @Mat'sMug It changes when you pour coffee into it! (It'd be cool if it were playable tho...)

Comment: Earl Grey is the best kind of tea.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that's going to be @Mat's next mug, too...

Comment: @Pops no chance. No mug can replace my SO mug. Except, well, a new SO mug =)

Comment: Really nice keyboard!

Answer (score 20):

Thanks Santa!

[image]

I've been wanting to learn C++ more in depth for quite a while now, and this book should certainly help. :)

Edit: It turns out there was more! :D

[image]

Comment: I love the use of a mountain picture there.  It does fit well with C++.

Answer (score 17):

Look what Santa brought me:

[image: Thanks Santa!]

Awesome!

*Oh productivity, how small thou art.*

It even has a note:

[image: Note]

Comment: The note says, "A gift **from** Mast". Is that intentional?

Comment: @SirPython Santa probably didn't want to give his identity away. I'm fairly confident I didn't send myself a book.

Comment: You wouldn't download a car..

Answer (score 16):

Thank you (still very much secret) Santa, that's indeed very delightful!

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Woah, my secret Santa really went above and beyond!

[image: Randall Munroe - Thing Explainer + What if? + Robert C. Martin - The Clean Coder]

Awesome!

Answer (score 14):

Thanks Santa! I think someone wants me to make a start up ;-)

[image]

For clarity, graphics card not included. That's mine :-)

Answer (score 14):

Thanks Santa! I received "*Clean Code*" by Robert C. Martin.

[image]

I'm sure this will be a great handbook for improving my reviews! :-)

Comment: *Nice*. /13characters

Comment: This book is awsome

Comment: One of the best written books on software development around.   Despite the focus on Java, most of it is generally applicable and as relevant to functional languages as OO ones.

Answer (score 14):

Just got mine today... Legend of Zelda mouse pad, gorgeous and perfect for this Nintendo Nerd! ;-)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let's hope this link doesn't die. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Oh yeah, it has finally arrived! :D

I received the most hyped word of 2015 as a gift.

I present you, the Cloud Storage!

[image]

[image]

Comment: LOL! That's awesome!

Answer (score 10):

Perfect!!! Got mine this afternoon too!

I imagine my "wish list" made it hard to decide, but this is a great choice for me. Much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I need to actually take photos (my bad), but thank you to my secret Santa, for the game and the **dragons!**

Comment: *bump* *poke* *bump again*

Comment: Take a photo dude @Zak!

Comment: I have (half) the photos. Just need to get home and take the other half.

Comment: Zaaaaaaaaaaak POST THE PICTURES

Comment: We still want those pictures :-)

Comment: @janos Holy crap. Yeah. Um, if they're not up by 19:00 yell at me until they are.

Comment: @Kaz Where are the bloody pictures, where are they? You're over a year late!

Comment: @Mast make that two ...